# How to modify the order of symbols to make the result more logical

Tags: equation-solving

[image]

```
Simplify[(1 - a) (1 - b)]
(-1 + a) (-1 + b)
```

How to modify the order of symbols to make the result more logical.
`(1-a)(1-b)`

Comment: The question arises: what for?

Comment: `TraditionalForm[(-1+a)(-1+b)]` returns `(a-1)(b-1)` but be very careful if you try to use the output of any `*Form` function. `*Form` functions are intended to make something pretty to look at, not something for further calculations. `MatrixForm` may be pretty to look at but `mymat=MatrixForm[...];Solve[mymat==...]` may fail.

Comment: `(-1 + a) (-1 + b)` seems more logical (one multiplication instead of three). (Is `(1-a)(1-b)` the more logical output you want? It's just there, not in a sentence.)

Answer (score 2):

**The function "rearrange"**

The function `rearrange[expr,listOfFinalPositions]` rewrites a sum in the order prescribed by the list entitled "listOfFinalPositions."

**Arguments**:

**expr** is the expression with the head Plus.

**listOfFinalPositions** is a list. It is important that its length must be equal to the length of the expression. It indicates the positions that the terms of the sum must take in the end. For example, for the expression a+b+c the listOfFinalPositions  {2,3,1}  means that a must go the second position, b - to the third and c - to the first one resulting in c+a+b

The function wraps the result by the HoldForm function to forbid an undesired reordering. Therefore, *to use the obtained expression further one needs to apply ReleaseHold*

```
rearrange[expr_, finalPositions_List] := Module[{lst, newlst},
   lst = List @@ expr;
   newlst = 
    Table[lst[[Position[finalPositions, i][[1, 1]]]], {i, 1, Length[lst]}];
   HoldForm[Evaluate[expr]] /. MapThread[Rule, {lst, newlst}]
   ];
```

**Examples**

*Example 1*:

Rearrange the sum

```
Clear[expr];
expr = a + b + c + d;
```

such that a stays on the second place, b- on the fourth, c - on the third and d - on the first one.

```
rearrange[expr, {2, 4, 3, 1}]
```

[image]

*Example 2*: transform (-a-b) (c-d) into (a+b) (d-c)

```
Clear[expr1, expr2, expr3];
expr1 = (-a - b) (c - d);
expr2 = MapAt[(-1)*HoldForm[Evaluate[(-1)*#]] &, expr1, {{1}, {2}}] //ReleaseHold;
expr3 = MapAt[rearrange[#, {2, 1}] &, expr2, {2}]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

The warning by @Bill in a comment about `*Form` functions is  well made.

The following works, but it appears that `PolymonialForm` is [still](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4783547/499167) undocumented?

```
PolynomialForm[Simplify[(1-a)(1-b)],TraditionalOrder->True]

(* (a-1) (b-1) *)
```